# Picture Connection on Facebook Real-Time Update API

Tags: facebook, image

In the real-time update API documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/), the "picture" connection is NOT in the list of connections of the user object to which we can subscribe to. But in the documentation for the real-time update API, they list the picture connection like:

***For example, to monitor changes to user's name, picture, friends, and News Feed, you would specify “name,picture,friends,feed”***

So can someone explain, why is this confusion in the documentation and tell me how we can subscribe to the picture connection?

Answer (score 1):

Picture is there under user's fields and connections. So you can subscribe for picture but can't specify that you want it from user's fields or from user's connections.